# Mono on ARM linux

Tags: c#, mono, arm, monodevelop, embedded-linux

i've crosscompile Mono for embedded linux on ARM9 processor.
But when i try to compile my first c# program "Hello world" i receive this
output from Mono:

```
Native stacktrace:


Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates

a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

used by your application.

=================================================================    

Aborted
```

I've googled but my problem is too generic.
Can someone explain the problem ?

Can i crosscompile the example file on pc (with Mono-arm compiler) end run
the binary on embedded-arm ?

i'll try to recompile without Mono-debugger.

Thanks

Comment: which release, how did you build it?

Comment: About "Can i crosscompile the example file on pc" - you do not have to *cross* compile, these binaries are platform-independent. Unless you want to build an AOT binary for ARM. Beside that, give us more details as IanNorton wrote.

Comment: I have the same issue. changing to 3.2 does not help.