# Cross compiling mono source for ARM?

Tags: mono, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile mono-2.10.5 source for arm using the steps in the link http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:ARM#Compiling_on_the_device. Installed scratch box in my PC. Most people suggesting the above link for cross compiling mono. But I couldn't do it.

I got an overall idea about cross compilation as follows:

1. Two stages of compilation needed.
2. The first one in my PC.
3. The second one within scratch box.
4. After that need to combine the resulting two install directories and copy that to my arm board.

   But I have some doubts in the above steps.

**Q** 1.1 In the first stage of compilation(within host PC) what all environment parameters needed ??

**Q** 1.2 whether steps given below are ok ?

**Q** 1.3 Is there anything to add with ./configure ?

```
 $ mkdir host-mono

 $ cd host-mono

 $ tar xzf ../mono-1.xx.tar.gz

 $ cd mono-1.xx

 $ ./configure

 $ make

 $ make install DESTDIR=`pwd`/tmptree
```

In the second stage within scratch box:

```
[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > mkdir cross

[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > cd cross

[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > tar xzf ../mono-1.xx.tar.gz

[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > cd arm-mono-1.xx

[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > ./configure --disable-mcs-build

[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > make 

[sbox-ARMEL: ~] > make install DESTDIR=`pwd`/tmptree
```

**Q** 2.1) How I can enter to arm-mono-1.xx directory ? After extracting(tar xzf ../mono-1.xx.tar.gz) we only get mono-1.xx right ?

**Q** 2.2) What all configuration I need to add with "./configure --disable-mcs-build " ?

**Q** 2.3) When I tried with "./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --disable-msc-build "
        resulted in configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling.

Can anyone help me ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cannot cross compile mono for arm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194610/cannot-cross-compile-mono-for-arm), also [ARM mono questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[arm]%20is%3aquestion%20mono) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006501/error-building-mono-in-scratchbox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030736/mono-on-arm-linux, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955314/cross-compile-mono-for-arm, etc.