# Error in cross compiling mono for arm

Tags: mono, arm, cross-compiling, ubuntu-12.04

I m trying to cross compile mono for arm architecture with help of scratchbox2 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS operating system but failed to do so.

The whole process I did is given below

**A. Setting Up scratchbox2**

1. Clone the scratchbox 2 repository:

   ```
   $ git clone git://gitorious.org/scratchbox2/scratchbox2.git
   ```
2. To build and install SB2:

   ```
   $ cd scratchbox2
   $ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
   $ cd ..
   $ sudo dpkg -i libsb2*deb scratchbox2*deb
   ```

Status: successful

**B. Setting up qemu**

1. Clone the qemu repository

   ```
   git clone git://git.qemu.org/qemu.git
   ```
2. To build and install qemu

   $ cd qemu
      $ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/sb2 --target-list=arm-linux-user
      $ make && make install
      $ cd ..

Status: successful

**C. Setting up arm tool chain**

1. Getting the arm tool chain

   ```
   $ wget https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/package8739/public/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2

   $ tar xjvf arm-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Generating a working target configuration.

   ```
   $ cp -a arm-2011.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/{lib,etc,usr} .
   $ sb2-init ARM9 arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc    [ ARM9-> name of target]
   ```

Status: successful

**D. Cross compiling mono**

```
   $ sb2

   [SB2 simple arm9] root@Vostro-460 $ cd Desktop/mono-2.10.8.1
   [SB2 simple arm9] root@Vostro-460 mono-2.10.8.1 $ ./configure --disable-mcs-build
   [SB2 simple arm9] root@Vostro-460 mono-2.10.8.1 $ make
```

Status: **failed**

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [test-glib] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ushus/Desktop/mono-2.10.8.1/eglib/test'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ushus/Desktop/mono-2.10.8.1/eglib'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ushus/Desktop/mono-2.10.8.1/eglib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ushus/Desktop/mono-2.10.8.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am stuck in this step. Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: And what will happen if you pass `--disable-tests` to configure?

Comment: same error. Should i cross compile glib for arm?

Comment: Other Possible duplicates: [ARM mono questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[arm]%20is%3aquestion%20mono) with [Mono scratchbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006501/error-building-mono-in-scratchbox), [Mono on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030736/mono-on-arm-linux), [Cross compile mono for ARM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955314/cross-compile-mono-for-arm), etc.